# For Loop in R Returns NA in Printing

Tags: r, for-loop, na

When I write the following simple for loop in R:

```
newlist <- c("A", "B", "C")
for (i in newlist) {
  print(newlist[i]) 
}
```

I get the following output:

```
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
```

I'm pretty new to R and coding in general?, can someone explain to me why it won't print out the letters one by one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `for` loop is iterating over the values of newlist, not their indices. That is, you are setting `i` to `"A"`, then `"B"`, etc, and then trying to subset `newlist` by the value, which returns an error because you can only subset using indices or names. What you probably want is:

```
for (i in 1:length(newlist)){
    print (newlist[i]))
}
```

Or, more simply,

```
for (i in newlist){
    print(i)
}
```